# Need advise in regex for Python

Tags: python, regex

Data recieved with API request from server. Data to parse:

```
b'{"Id":"9e46ba44-2b89-4f9d-88eb-5b5dcfe908e0","Name":"\xd0\x9a\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb 89","AltEnabled":true,"ReceiveVideoMbps":2.6148132324218749,"ReceiveAltVideoMbps":0.18560943603515626,"WriteVideoMbps":2.5809969113862512,"Status":"Ok"}'
b'{"Id":"ef666ea5-fe40-4c9c-8953-1b2c5ddda4ad","Name":"\xd0\x9a\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb 68","AltEnabled":true,"ReceiveVideoMbps":0.33305744615277988,"ReceiveAltVideoMbps":0.0349517822265625,"WriteVideoMbps":0.33188474615605063,"Status":"Ok"}'
```

This regex gives me "Id" and "Name":

```
regex = b"{\"Id\":\"(?P<id>.*?)\",\"Name\":\"(?P<name>.*?)\""
```

But I can't parse "ReceiveVideoMbps" parameter.

How should I update regex to start to parse "ReceiveVideoMbps" parameter?

Comment: Are there any particular reasons why this string isn't being parsed as JSON?

Comment: Do you want to parse this whole string using JSON instead of regex? If so, I can help.

Comment: Regex is best suited for such a simple task.
But thank you for reminder about json! I forgot about it.

Comment: Data received through API is usually in JSON format, so it's the best way to parse it.

Comment: Regex is absolutely **not** best suited for parsing JSON; a JSON parser is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the regex as:

```
regex = r"{\"Id\":\"(?P<id>.*?)\",\"Name\":\"(?P<name>.*?)\",.*,\"ReceiveAltVideoMbps\":(?P<rec>.*?),.*"
```

Which would result in something like:

```
Group `id`  9e46ba44-2b89-4f9d-88eb-5b5dcfe908e0
Group `name`    \xd0\x9a\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb 89
Group `rec` 0.18560943603515626
```

Comment: Nice one!
It works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This type of string can be parsed efficiently using `JSON` instead of `re`.

I am showing you both ways. However, you need to convert your `bytes` objects to `string` equivalents using `decode()` method before you perform any parsing.

**The Regex Way**

**Code**

```py
import re
x = b'{"Id":"9e46ba44-2b89-4f9d-88eb-5b5dcfe908e0","Name":"\xd0\x9a\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb 89","AltEnabled":true,"ReceiveVideoMbps":2.6148132324218749,"ReceiveAltVideoMbps":0.18560943603515626,"WriteVideoMbps":2.5809969113862512,"Status":"Ok"}'
regex = re.compile(r"{\"Id\":\"(?P<id>.*?)\",\"Name\":\"(?P<name>.*?)\",.*,\"ReceiveVideoMbps\":(?P<rec>.*?),.*")
items = regex.findall(x.decode())
print(items)
```

**Output**

The output will be a list of tuples.

```
[('9e46ba44-2b89-4f9d-88eb-5b5dcfe908e0', 'Канал 89', '2.6148132324218749')]
```

**The JSON Way**

**Code**

```py
import json
x = b'{"Id":"9e46ba44-2b89-4f9d-88eb-5b5dcfe908e0","Name":"\xd0\x9a\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb 89","AltEnabled":true,"ReceiveVideoMbps":2.6148132324218749,"ReceiveAltVideoMbps":0.18560943603515626,"WriteVideoMbps":2.5809969113862512,"Status":"Ok"}'
items = json.loads(x.decode())

print(items)
```

**Output**

The output is a dictionary.

```
{'AltEnabled': True,
 'Id': '9e46ba44-2b89-4f9d-88eb-5b5dcfe908e0',
 'Name': 'Канал 89',
 'ReceiveAltVideoMbps': 0.18560943603515626,
 'ReceiveVideoMbps': 2.614813232421875,
 'Status': 'Ok',
 'WriteVideoMbps': 2.580996911386251}
```

Now, you can access the elements using `dict` keys.

**Example**

```py
print(items['Id'])  # 9e46ba44-2b89-4f9d-88eb-5b5dcfe908e0
print(items['Name']) # Канал 89
print(items['ReceiveVideoMbps']) # 2.614813232421875
```

Comment: Thank you for you advise! This is comprehensive solution.

Comment: If it solved your issue, please mark the answer as Accepted

Comment: @Evgeny, if you found it as comprehensive, you should have accepted the answer.